# Blocking a sender in gmail

Tags: c#

I am developing a application blocking a sender in gmail filter through c#.net.
I am a using gmail api to block a sender using the following line,

```
GoogleMailSettingsService service = new GoogleMailSettingsService("yourdomain", "your-apps");
```

what is "yourdomain" and "your-apps" fields.

Or

Kindly advice how to block a sender in gmail thorough a c#.net code.

Answer (score 0):

The Google API is specified here [Email Settings Developers Guide](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/email_settings/developers_guide_protocol.html)